# Why isn't this regex matching the expected way?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to get rid of the slash character in case it exists at the end of my string. I used the following expression, intending to match *any character not being slash at the end of the line*.

```
var str = "http://hazaa.com/blopp/";
str.match("[^/$]+", "g");
```

For some reason (surely logical and explainable but not graspabled to me on my own), I get the split into three string looking as follows.

> ["http:", "hazaa.com", "blopp"]

1. What am I assuming wrongly?
2. How to resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current regex will *match* the portion of string until the first `/` or `$` is encountered. The second parameter is ignored; there is no second parameter for [`String.match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match).

To remove the trailing slash, use the [`String.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) function:

```
var str = "http://hazaa.com/blopp/";
str = str.replace(/\/$/, "");
console.log(str);
// "http://hazaa.com/blopp"
```

If you need to check whether a string ends with a slash, use the `String.match` method like this:

```
var str = "http://hazaa.com/blopp/";
var match = str.match(/\/$/);
console.log(match);
// null if string does not end with /
// ["/"] if string ends with a /
```

If you need to grab every thing except the last character(s) being `/`, use this:

```
var r = /(.+?)\/*$/;
console.log("http://hazaa.com/blopp//".match(r)); // ["http://hazaa.com/blopp//", "http://hazaa.com/blopp"]
console.log("http://hazaa.com/blopp/".match(r)); // ["http://hazaa.com/blopp/", "http://hazaa.com/blopp"]
console.log("http://hazaa.com/bloppA".match(r)); // ["http://hazaa.com/bloppA", "http://hazaa.com/bloppA"]
```

The 2nd index in the returned array contains the desired portion of the URL. The regex works as follows:

- `(.+?)` un-greedy match (and capture) any character
- `\/*$` matches optional trailing slash(es)

The first portion regex is intentionally changed to un-greedy. If it was greedy, it would attempt to find the biggest match as long the the whole regex matches (consuming the trailing `/` in the process). When ungreedy, it will find the smallest match as long as the whole regex matches.

Comment: OK, that actually answers both (1) and (2) but begs another question. How should one put regex if one is to match (not replace, any more) all characters except for a trailing slash? I was trying `str.match("^(/$)", "g")` but failed.

Comment: @agstudy and Salman: Running `"http://hazaa.com/blopp/".match(/\/$/, "")` I get the slash. I'd like to get all-but-slash.

Answer (score 4):

In `str.match("[^/$]+", "g");`, why put dollar sign inside bracket? It's supposed to be outside, namely, `str.match("[^/]+$", "g");`.

To remove all the trailing slash, you can use `str.replace(/\/+$/, "")`. (If you'd like to remove the last trailing slash ONLY, remove the `+` in the `replace`'s regex)

Update:

One more way that doesn't use `replace`:

```
function stripEndingSlashes(str) {
    var matched = str.match("(.*[^/]+)/*$");
    return matched ? matched[1] : "";
}
```

Comment: Nope. Wrong results. That will only match *blopp*.

Comment: I just point out that `[^/$]+` make no sense in your problem(It will match any string that contains any characters except '/' or '$'), while `[^/]+$` means any string that ends with 'non-slash' character.

Comment: Not to be picky but the upvote is surprising. The suggested answer is **wrong**.

Comment: I updated my answer. Again, I haven't suggested a solution at first, just pointed out that the regex you used was wrong, which is most crucial in your problem. This time I gave an actual solution.

Comment: Right, when we match the end-of-line-slash, we can use *replace* to obtain the rest. However, of pure curiosity, I wonder how to **match** the rest, instead of the end-of-line-slash. Is it doable at all?

Comment: Yes, use parenthese and group.

Comment: Care to exemplify? I'm not precisely savvy at this, as you understand. :)

Comment: Maybe you can refer this link( http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/regular-expressions-in-javascript-part-2/ ) which gives some examples for group expression.

Comment: @AndreasJohansson I updated my answer to make use of group expression for your sake.

Comment: Nice. Thanks! I got it now. I was, apparently, more ignorant of regex than what I knew! :)

Answer (score 2):

The regexp is choosing "everything except slash". That is why `match()` returns the parts of the string between slashes.

You can resolve it with the `replace()` function:

```
var str = "http://hazaa.com/blopp/";
//replace the last slash with an empty string to remove it
str = str.replace(/\/$/,'');
```

The regexp literal should always be surrounded between `/` characters. So here the regexp is:

- `\/` : this means a single slash character. In order to prevent Javascript from interpreting your slash as the end of regexp, it needs to be 'escaped' with a backslash.
- `$` : this means the end of the string

Answer (score 0):

Why use regex? Just check if the last symbol of the string is a slash and then slice. Like this:

```
if (str.slice(-1) === '/') {
  str = str.slice(0, -1);
}
```

Comment: For learning. I wish to know how to do that in order to apply to a more complicated problem.

Comment: `str.slice(-1) == "/"` is shorter.

Comment: How about if str has multiple trailing slashes? Yes, you can still resolve that without regex, but regex is much more succinct.

Comment: @Hui Zheng: I doubt in a url there would be more than one trailing slashes but you're right...

Comment: `str.slice(0, -1)` is shorter too. You can totally omit `.length` from your example.